# microsoft azure sql v12 in-memory table max size

Tags: size, azure-sql-database, in-memory

What is the maximum table size of in-memory tables on microsoft azure sql (v12) databases? For the different service tiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [In-Memory OLTP tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx) - this is not yet supported in Azure SQL DB v12.

Please clarify if you are referring to something else.